Two animations in the same graphic (ECHARTS)
I tried triggering two animations after clicking a button. The first animation moves the center of the gauge upwards (and this works). The second (which doesn't work) would be to move the pointers randomly and return to the initial value, as configured in the code below:


const mychartspider1 = echarts.init(document.getElementById("gaugespiderinc1"));
const maxValue = 100;
const numPointers = 4; // Number of pointers
let randomValuesInterval;
let randomColorsInterval;
let centerAnimationInterval;

function getRandomValue(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function setRandomValues() {
  let data = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < numPointers; i++) {
    data.push({
      value: getRandomValue(0, maxValue),
    });
  }

  updateGaugeSpider(data);
}

function updateGaugeSpider(data) {
  option = {
    series: [
      {
        type: "gauge",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        splitNumber: 10,
        radius: "75%",
        center: ["50%", "150%"],
        axisLine: {
          lineStyle: {
            color: [[1, "#49a6de"]],
            width: 3.5,
          },
        },
        splitLine: {
          distance: -28,
          length: 28,
          lineStyle: {
            width: 5,
            color: "#49a6de",
          },
        },
        axisTick: {
          distance: -12,
          length: 10,
          lineStyle: {
            width: 2,
            color: "#49a6de",
          },
        },
        axisLabel: {
          distance: -64,
          color: "#49a6de",
          fontSize: 36,
          fontFamily: "D-DIN",
          textStyle: {
            textBorderWidth: 1,
            textBorderColor: "#020202",
          },
        },
        anchor: {
          show: true,
          size: 25,
          itemStyle: {
            borderColor: "#020202",
            borderWidth: 2,
          },
        },
        pointer: {
          offsetCenter: [0, "10%"],
          icon: "path://M2090.36389,615.30999 L2090.36389,615.30999 C2091.48372,615.30999 2092.40383,616.194028 2092.44859,617.312956 L2096.90698,728.755929 C2097.05155,732.369577 2094.2393,735.416212 2090.62566,735.56078 C2090.53845,735.564269 2090.45117,735.566014 2090.36389,735.566014 L2090.36389,735.566014 C2086.74736,735.566014 2083.81557,732.63423 2083.81557,729.017692 C2083.81557,728.930412 2083.81732,728.84314 2083.82081,728.755929 L2088.2792,617.312956 C2088.32396,616.194028 2089.24407,615.30999 2090.36389,615.30999 Z",
          length: "115%",
          itemStyle: {
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: "#020202",
            shadowOffsetX: 4,
            shadowOffsetY: 4,
            shadowColor: "#020202",
            shadowBlur: 10,
          },
        },
        detail: {
          valueAnimation: true,
          borderWidth: 3,
          borderColor: "#858383",
          borderRadius: 5,
          color: "#020202",
          fontWeight: "bold",
          width: 23,
          height: 18,
          fontSize: 20,
          fontFamily: "DS-Digital",
          formatter: function (value) {
            return value.toFixed(0) + "%";
          },
        },
        data: data.map((item, index) => {
          const colors = ["#dd4b39", "orange", "lime", "cyan"];
          const titleName = ["Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3", "Name 4"];
          const offsetName = [
            ["-45%", "70%"],
            ["-15%", "70%"],
            ["15%", "70%"],
            ["45%", "70%"],
          ];
          const offsetDetail = [
            ["-45%", "84%"],
            ["-15%", "84%"],
            ["15%", "84%"],
            ["45%", "84%"],
          ];
          return {
            value: item.value,
            itemStyle: {
              color: colors[index % colors.length],
            },
            name: titleName[index % titleName.length],
            title: {
              offsetCenter: offsetName[index % offsetName.length],
              color: colors[index % colors.length],
            },
            detail: {
              backgroundColor: colors[index % colors.length],
              offsetCenter: offsetDetail[index % offsetDetail.length],
            },
          };
        }),
      },
      {
        type: "gauge",
        min: 0,
        max: 60,
        splitNumber: 6,
        radius: "70%",
        center: ["50%", "150%"],
        axisLine: {
          lineStyle: {
            color: [[1, "#fee200"]],
            width: 3.5,
          },
        },
        splitLine: {
          distance: 10,
          length: 28,
          lineStyle: {
            width: 5,
            color: "#fee200",
          },
        },
        axisTick: {
          show: false,
        },
        axisLabel: {
          distance: 10,
          fontSize: 33,
          color: "#fee200",
          fontFamily: "D-DIN",
          textStyle: {
            textBorderWidth: 1,
            textBorderColor: "#020202",
          },
        },
        pointer: {
          show: false,
        },
        title: {
          show: false,
        },
        anchor: {
          show: true,
          size: 14,
          itemStyle: {
            color: "#f00",
            borderColor: "#020202",
            borderWidth: 1,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  };

  mychartspider1.setOption(option);
}

let colorIndex = 0; // Variável para controlar o índice da cor a ser aplicada

function setNextColor() {
  const colors = ["#f00", "#49a6de"];
  const color = colors[colorIndex]; // Seleciona a cor atual com base no índice
  colorIndex = (colorIndex + 1) % colors.length; // Atualiza o índice para a próxima cor
  return color;
}

function setRandomColors() {
  const color = setNextColor(); // Obtém a próxima cor sequencialmente
  mychartspider1.setOption({
    series: [
      {
        axisLabel: {
          color: color,
        },
        axisLine: {
          lineStyle: {
            color: [[1, color]],
          },
        },
        splitLine: {
          lineStyle: {
            color: color,
          },
        },
        axisTick: {
          lineStyle: {
            color: color,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  });
}

// Button click event
$("#startgaugeeffectbtnanimation1").one("click", function () {
  // Configure random values and colors initially
  setRandomValues();
  setRandomColors();

  // Update random values and colors every 500 milliseconds for 5 seconds
  randomValuesInterval = setInterval(setRandomValues, 500);
  randomColorsInterval = setInterval(setRandomColors, 500);

  setTimeout(() => {
    // Stop updating after 5 seconds
    clearInterval(randomValuesInterval);
    clearInterval(randomColorsInterval);

    // Restore input values
    let value1 = Number($("#number1").val());
    let value2 = Number($("#number2").val());
    let value3 = Number($("#number3").val());
    let value4 = Number($("#number4").val());
    updateGaugeSpiderFromInputs(value1, value2, value3, value4);
  }, 5000);
});

function updateGaugeSpiderFromInputs(value1, value2, value3, value4) {
  value1 = Number($("#number1").val());
  value2 = Number($("#number2").val());
  value3 = Number($("#number3").val());
  value4 = Number($("#number4").val());

  // Verifique se o intervalo está definido e, se sim, pare a animação
  if (randomValuesInterval) {
    clearInterval(randomValuesInterval);
    clearInterval(randomColorsInterval);
  }

  // Defina as cores finais diretamente
  updateGaugeSpider([
    {
      value: value1,
    },
    {
      value: value2,
    },
    {
      value: value3,
    },
    {
      value: value4,
    },
  ]);
}

// Input change event
$("#number1, #number2, #number3, #number4").on("change", function () {
  updateGaugeSpiderFromInputs();
});

updateGaugeSpiderFromInputs();

// animation center downUp
// Função para iniciar a animação do centro do gauge para '50%'
function startCenterAnimation() {
  let centerPosition = 150; // Inicializa a posição central
  let startTime; // Armazena o horário de início da animação

  function animateCenterChange(timestamp) {
    const duration = 5000; // Duração da animação em milissegundos
    const startValue = centerPosition; // Valor inicial da posição central
    const endValue = 50; // Valor final da posição central
    const progress = (timestamp - startTime) / duration; // Progresso da animação

    // Calcula o próximo valor da posição central com base no progresso
    const nextValue = startValue + (endValue - startValue) * progress;

    // Define o centro do gráfico com base no próximo valor
    mychartspider1.setOption({
      series: [
        {
          center: ["50%", nextValue + "%"],
        },
        {
          center: ["50%", nextValue + "%"],
        },
      ],
    });

    // Continua a animação se ainda não atingiu o fim
    if (progress < 1) {
      requestAnimationFrame(animateCenterChange);
    }
  }

  function handleClick() {
    startTime = performance.now(); // Obtém o horário de início da animação
    requestAnimationFrame(animateCenterChange); // Inicia a animação
  }

  document
    .getElementById("startgaugeeffectbtnanimation1")
    .addEventListener("click", handleClick, {
      once: true,
    });
}

// Inicializa a animação do centro do gauge quando o botão for clicado
startCenterAnimation();
#gaugespiderinc1 {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}

body {
  background: #333;
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.5.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<input type="range" id="number1" min="0" max="100" value="25">
<input type="range" id="number2" min="0" max="100" value="50">
<input type="range" id="number3" min="0" max="100" value="75">
<input type="range" id="number4" min="0" max="100" value="100">

<div id='gaugespiderinc1'></div>

<button id='startgaugeeffectbtnanimation1'>
  Click me
</button>



See that the center animation works perfectly, but the pointers don't move. Also note that the detail of the gauge is moving and the value is stopping according to the values of the HTML inputs, but I need the pointers to move randomly during the center animation (at the same time).

Issues
The problem , I could identify is that animating the pointer itself is not happening. You're updating the value property of the data option, which updates the final position of the pointer but not the animation path.

Update the pointer.animation property:

We can leverage the use of your updateGaugeSpider function, by adding the animation property to the pointer object:
updateGaugeSpider(data) {
  option = {
    // ... your existing options
    series: [{
      // ... your existing gauge options
      pointer: {
        offsetCenter: [0, "10%"],
        icon: "",
        length: "115%",
        itemStyle: {
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: "#020202",
          shadowOffsetX: 4,
          shadowOffsetY: 4,
          shadowColor: "#020202",
          shadowBlur: 10,
        },
        animation: {
          // Set animation duration and easing here
          duration: 1000, 
          easing: 'sinInOut' 
        }
      },
     
    },
    ]
  };
  
  mychartspider1.setOption(option);
}


Then update the pointer value inside the animation loop:
Within your startCenterAnimation function, modify the animateCenterChange function to update both the center position and the pointer value:
modified your code a abit

function animateCenterChange(timestamp) {
  const duration = 5000;
  const startValue = centerPosition; 
  const endValue = 50; 
  const progress = (timestamp - startTime) 

  
  const nextValue = startValue + (endValue - startValue) * progress;

  // pointer values
  const newData = data.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    value: getRandomValue(0, maxValue), // Generate random value for each pointer
  }));

  // Update chart options
  mychartspider1.setOption({
    series: [{
      center: ['50%', nextValue + '%'],
      data: newData
    },
    {
      center: ['50%', nextValue + '%']
    }]
  });

  if (progress < 1) {
    requestAnimationFrame(animateCenterChange);
  }
}

We should be green at this point...
